# Ajax jQuery POST variable not set

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, post

**Problem:**

I make an ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "cms/php/UploadAjax.php",
    data: {
        Images: Images
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

The structure of `Images` is like this:

```
Array
{
    [0]=> Array
    {
        [0]=>"test1.png"
        [1]=>"someDataUrl1"
    }
    [1]=> Array
    {
        [0]=>"test2.png"
        [1]=>"someDataUrl2"
    }
}
```

On my local server (Windows/EasyPHP) I'm able to access `$_POST['Images']` just fine, like

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Images']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['Images'] as $image)
        {
            ////do something with $image[0], $image[1]
            if (!preg_match('/data:([^;]*);base64,(.*)/', $image[0], $matches)) 
        {
            die("error");
        }
        // Decode the data
        $content = base64_decode($matches[2]);


        header('Content-Type: '.$matches[1]);
        header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content)); ////Removing it resolved the issue
        $imagename=utf8_decode($image[1]);
        $path="../../galleryimages/".$imagename;
        $mysqlpath="galleryimages/".$image[1];
        file_put_contents($path,$content);

        }
    }
    else
        echo "something";
?>
```

Problem is, this is not working on my online server. It gives the warning:

```
POST http://myurl.com/... net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
```

If I then add:

```
contentType:"html/text"
```

to my ajax call, I'm getting no error but the `console.log(data);` from the success handler gives me "*something*", which tells me that `$_POST['Images']` is not set. With `contentType` added, It neither works offline nor online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change the dataType form "html" to "json"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it: Removing

```
   header('Content-Length: '.strlen($content));
```

solved the problem (also see my question).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you. This will turn the array into json, which is something php can decode and use as an array.

```
var ImageJSON = JSON.stringify(Images);

  data: {
     Images: ImageJSON,
  }
```

Before you send it.

```
if(isset($_POST['Images']))
    $Images = json_decode($_POST['Images']);

    foreach($Images as $image) {
```